# MVC displays month and date backwards

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display a date as dd/MM/yyyy, but it keeps showing as MM/dd/yyyy in the view.

Model:

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
[Required]
public DateTime? HireDate { get; set; }
```

View:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.HireDate)
```

Comment: try `modelItem => item.HireDate.toString('dd/MM/yyyy')`

Comment: With that, I get an error - "No overload for method 'ToString' takes 1 argument.

Comment: that is because it a nullable date, try `modelItem => (DateTime)item.HireDate.toString('dd/MM/yyyy')`

Comment: Still get the same error. Also tried item.HireDate.Value.toString('dd/MM/YYYY'), but it didn't work either. Any other thoughts?

Comment: What do you have set under **Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats -> Short Date**?

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - good call! It was set to M/d/yyyy. Changing and rebuilding the project solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this solved OP's problem:

What do you have set under Control Panel -> Region and Language -> Formats -> Short Date?

Comment: Changed setting to dd-MMM-yyyy